# Android TextField editable = false property issue

Tags: android, titanium, textfield, appcelerator-titanium

I found an issue on TextField with property

> editable = "false"

Notice that, i work on **Titanium Studio** and the issue concern only **Android Platform.**

Consider a simple window with 2 textfield, the first one have editable property set to false, the second is editable.

Now, run the app, try to enter the first textfield => you can't because is not editable, so is expected behaviour.

Next enter into the second textField which is editable, the soft keyboard get opened and you can enter some text.

Now, don't close the soft keyboard, and tap on the first textfield (the soft keyboard is still opened), you can now enter some text into the first TextField which is normally not editable !

So, somebody have an idea to solve this behaviour ?

```
Orating System
Name                        = Mac OS X
Version                     = 10.11.3
Architecture                = 64bit
# CPUs                      = 4
Memory                      = 17179869184
Node.js
Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
Titanium SDK
SDK Version                 = 5.2.0.GA
SDK Path                    = /Users/Me/#/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA
Target Platform             = android
```

Comment: Use an EditText instead of a TextView and don't even mess with the editable property.

Comment: I work with Titanium Studio, so i work with TextField

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed it. Fail on my part.